# VF template displaying blank information for a profile

Tags: visualforce

I created a VF template with controller and component for approval process. All recepient can see all values of template. But one profile cannot see becasue it has force.com free user license which does not have access to account and order object. Can any one share idea how I can show this data (Account and Order Product) to that particular profile for the vf template?

Comment: You could make the controller `without sharing`, though it might violate your agreements with Salesforce.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I just tried without sharing , but still the same issue .